# PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd stored procedure query with multiple input variables

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I've got a SQL Server stored procedure that I'm trying to run via PowerShell but just can't the syntax for multiple parameters to work.

The stored procedure requires 3 input parameters but any (or all) of these could have multiple values being passed into it. I can pass a single variable in just fine but get errors when I try to add multiple values.

```
$SqlItems = "Items='0212014080804','0212014080630','0212014080620'"
$SQLLogs =  "Lobs=''"
$SQLCodes = "CC=''"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "EXEC proc_BS_Course_Migration @Items=`$(Items), @Lobs=`$(Logs), @CC=`$(CC)" -Variable $SQLItems, $SQLLogs, $SQLCodes
```

When `$SqlItems = "Items='0212014080804'"` the code above works fine. As soon as any of these variables grow longer the script dies (works fine within SQL itself)

I'm running PowerShell 5, SQL Server 2012 in case it matters

Comment: Could you provide the parameter declaration statements to your stored procedure?  As it is right now it is hard to determine what the parameters are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? This is the recommend way:

`Invoke-SQLCommand -connectionString $sqlConnStr -commandText "proc_BS_Course_Migration" -commandType StoredProcedure -parameters @{"@Items" = "'0212014080804','0212014080630','0212014080620'", "@Lobs" = "''", "@CC" = "''" }`

Comment: The -Parameters argument does not exist.  I checked the MS docs on Invoke-Sqlcmd and checked the latest installed module 21.1.18068.

Comment: at first I thought this was referring to Invoke-Sqlcmd, until I looked closer.  Did a quick search and I think you were referring to:
[Invoke-SqlCommand](https://github.com/michaellwest/PowerShell-Modules/blob/master/CorpApps/Invoke-SqlCommand.ps1)
or something to that effect.

Would be better to qualify that in your answer since it could cause confusion and the original question was in reference to:
[sqlps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/?view=sqlserver-ps) or
[SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps)